# Unsupported scope "proxied email" - Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook

I want to get the emails of my friends using FQL, so I pass the permission "proxied_email" to Facebook SDK. It shows error on FB dialog:

```
"Invalid parameter. Error message: Unsupported scrop: "proxied_email".
I think this is a bug
```

Apparently [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) says that I need the permission "proxied_email"

Is it a bug???

By the way, I can't [get the email](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20uid,%20name,%20email,%20current_location,%20pic_square%20from%20user%20where%20uid%20in%20%28select%20uid2%20from%20friend%20where%20uid1=me%28%29%29%20order%20by%20name%20limit%200,%2015), it always returns null. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`proxied_email` is not a permission, but a field in the `User` FQL table. This is why you get an error.

You must ask for the `email` permission to get the email.

Here is how to get the `email`:

```
SELECT email FROM user WHERE uid=USER_ID
```